# Startup Application Preferences - SSH Key Agent

Tags: startup

I am Using Ubuntu 18.04 and i am new.
I would like to know what is this SSH Key Agent and what will happen if i remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SSH key agent can stores SSH keys, which are password protected. It provides a easy interface to the [ssh-agent](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ssh-agent.1.html) from the terminal. If you don't use password protected SSH keys, you can remove it without any impact.